calculating drain current
I am doing a practice question where I'm supposed to find a drain current for a figure, shown in the light blue box in the picture below (along with my calculations).
The red writing is the equation I've gotten by applying KCL.
In order to find Id as the question asked me to, I tried to find Vg first by using a graphing calculator after plugging in the values for the rest of the variables, but I end up with 0.4005 instead of the 0.807 I'm supposed to get according to the answer key given.
Any help on what I might have gotten wrong or missed would be greatly appreciated!


nevermind, i've figured out my problem!

It is perfectly acceptable for you to delete your question.
